# QGIS VPAT; Section 1194.21(c)

Tags: qgis

I am attempting to fill out a [VPAT](http://www.state.gov/documents/organization/126552.pdf) for QGIS so that it can be made more accessible in the federal IT environment. I could use some help and wanted to explore this venue as a means of getting it. If you are familiar with the QGIS codebase, federal IT accreditation, or rely on assistive technology you may have insight which could be useful for greatly expanding the audience for this wonderful software.

Format: I will post the section of the VPAT in question below. Below that I will try and translate the section into a more easily digestable format. I am looking for anybody who can speak to **the level of support QGIS provides to meet this item specified**. **Specific technical information about what features QGIS has that helps it to do this are also useful. If QGIS does not meet this and you know why I would also like to know this and have it documented.**

Section 1194.21(c): "A well-defined on-screen indication of the current focus shall be provided that moves among interactive interface elements as the input focus changes. The focus shall be programmatically exposed so that Assistive Technology can track focus and focus changes."

In other words: "The point of action (e.g., cursor) is easy to find and is programmatically exposed to AT(Assistive Technology) so that AT can track focus and focus changes."

Anyone have any insight? If this works out I may be posting similar items from the VPAT that I have struggled answering myself.

Comment: .If you haven't found it yet the qgis-dev group wil most likely have more definitive answers for this question in particular. http://lists.osgeo.org/mailman/listinfo/qgis-developer

Answer (score 0):

I just want to update this because @DSaeger got their answer and put the VPAT at [qgis.org/en/about-qgis/vpatm.html (archived)](http://web.archive.org/web/20130509053144/http://www.qgis.org/en/about-qgis/vpatm.html)

This is useful for those of us wanting to use this software in government.