# Looking for a VPAT for QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, accessibility

I am looking for a VPAT for QGIS 3. I am in the US and trying to assist a faculty member who needs the VPAT before their college will install QGIS on their computers. I saw that @DSaeger asked a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53454/qgis-vpat-section-1194-21c) about a QGIS VPAT 10 years ago but the link to that VPAT is no longer functional and was for QGIS 1. Is there an updated link or does anyone have any new information on a VPAT for QGIS 3?

Comment: I've updated the broken link in the [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/53454/qgis-vpat-section-1194-21c) to point to the [web archive version of the original](http://web.archive.org/web/20130509053144/http://www.qgis.org/en/about-qgis/vpatm.html).  I have no further information other than that.

Comment: Thank you so much!